# C3064 Snmp High CPU Utilization

Tags: nx-os

I have a N3K-C3064PQ-10GX and i have 350 Vlans on it and i am monitoring it from 2x server (one of them is observium and other one is prtg) and i have applied an acl on my uplink to drop snmp packets and snmptrap packet except for my trusted ips. but yesterday from 9.00PM my cpu load was at %70 and prolonged up to 11.00pm and when i execute 'show process cpu sort' the output was :

```
PID    Runtime(ms)  Invoked   uSecs  1Sec    Process
-----  -----------  --------  -----  ------  -----------
 3530     21871511  143773394    152  25.54%  snmpd
 3613          418      3372    124  20.79%  netstack
 3395    121460885  2147483647     45  11.85%  bcm_usd
 3534          124        66   1881   0.94%  adjmgr
 3569          211      2116     99   0.94%  arp
 3453      2884415  20002223    144   0.44%  ipfib
 3679      1522539  46052299     33   0.44%  cfs
```

so the snmp was using the most cpu,
i have checked with debug snmp pkt to see if i am receiving many packets but i see only 3 packet per 30 second then i was checking my uplink mirror and I see there was no attack and everything was working properly and i did not find anything strange,
here is my sh ver output :

```
Software
  BIOS:      version 2.8.0
  loader:    version N/A
  kickstart: version 6.0(2)U6(7)
  system:    version 6.0(2)U6(7)
  Power Sequencer Firmware:
             Module 1: version v1.0
  SFP uC:    version 2.12
  BIOS compile time:       12/22/2015
  kickstart image file is: bootflash:///n3000-uk9-kickstart.6.0.2.U6.7.bin
  kickstart compile time:  7/28/2016 9:00:00 [07/28/2016 20:10:23]
  system image file is:    bootflash:///n3000-uk9.6.0.2.U6.7.bin
  system compile time:     7/28/2016 9:00:00 [07/28/2016 20:42:38]
```

the only thing that i guess is that was a bug or procotol flap or such things, can anyone help me on this?
i have in mind to upgrade my switch to nxos.7.0.3.I7.8 as this is the cisco suggested nxos.
if this case happen again what thing should i check?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you check the output of: show proc cpu history and confirm that high cpu usage started after ACL was applied?

Comment: before high cpu usages started i had ACL on my uplink and i did not have any change before the high usages (at least for 2 days ago) and everything was untouched

Comment: Ok can you disable collecting on snmp servers for this device but don't touch anything on nexus so nexus should be still sending snmp to server but server will just ignore it. This should help us identify whether we have issue with nexus or snmp server. If cpu is still high then reenable collecting on snmp servers for this device and do port mirroring or use wireshark on snmp server links and check if there is any excessive number of packets from nexus (even if debugging showing only 3 packets per 30 sec). If no excessive packets then I would upgrade IOS.

Comment: during high cpu usages i have disabled my snmp community on nxos side for 10-15minutes but i had high cpu usages then i reenable my snmp community then pause my monitoring (PRTG and observium) then wait 10minutes and i had high cpu usages and also i have a full mirror from my uplink and i am analyze them with FastNetMon so i will detect attack with fastnetmon but there was nothing strange, also i have denied all snmp traffic on my acl so no snmp pkt should received and process by switch, the only guess i have is bug withing my nxos, does not it?

Comment: ok then I would give it a shot and upgrade ios because like you said it might be a bug even tho I cant find any related to snmp for this device or release.

Comment: That is an absolutely ancient NXOS version.  The latest train is literally 9.3.  There very likely are issues with the snmp process and there definitely are open PSIRT’s.  I would not run that code version exposed to customers or the general Internet.

Comment: as i read in cisco website the suggested version for 3064 is nxos.7.0.3.I7.8 , so do you think its ok to upgrade to this version? @rnxrx

Comment: because as i see 9.3 is around 1.8g and 3064pq has only 1.5gbps and 1.2gbps free :D so i think the best version is nxos.7.0.3.I7.8 which cisco suggested, am i right? also i can upgrade to nxos.7.0.3.I7.9 but i think the suggested version is better

Comment: nxos.7.0.3.I7.8.bin is from March 2020 so it's really fresh

Comment: 7.0(3)I7 is a long-lived train - any changes at this point are basically bug fixes, rather than new features.  There will be release notes describing what got fixed.  Truthfully either version is going to be a vast improvement over a 6.x release.  Make sure you read the release notes thoroughly - there may be an intermediate 6.x version that you need to hit before going up to 7.